# Puzzle with PictureBoxes bug

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image that is chopped into 4 pieces (2x2). I draw them in a random order and if the order of the small pics are correct write out "You win".
If you click on an image then it should be swap with the another next to it.
If you click the left button first change position with the third (right button 2-4). What is the problem with the code?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Collections;


    namespace SimplePuzzle
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void buttonVéletlen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                Mix();
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("img\\1.png");
                pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("img\\2.png");
                pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("img\\3.png");
                pictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile("img\\4.png");

            }
            int[] arr = new int[4];

            void Mix()
            {

                Random rnd = new Random();

                int n = 4;

                // Fill array 1-4
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = i + 1;
                }
                // Rnd array

                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    int one = rnd.Next(n);
                    int another = rnd.Next(n);
                    int temp = arr[one];
                    arr[one] = arr[another];
                    arr[another] = temp;

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i].ToString());
                }

                // PictureBox1
                if (arr[0]==0)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox1.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[0] == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox1.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[0] == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox1.Top = 150;
                }

                if (arr[0] == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox1.Top = 150;
                }

                // PictureBox2
                if (arr[1] == 0)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox2.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[1] == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox2.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[1] == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox2.Top = 150;
                }

                if (arr[1] == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox2.Top = 150;
                }

                // PictureBox3
                if (arr[2] == 0)
                {
                    pictureBox3.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox3.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[2] == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox3.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox3.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[2] == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox3.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox3.Top = 150;
                }

                if (arr[2] == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox3.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox3.Top = 150;
                }

                // PictureBox4
                if (arr[3] == 0)
                {
                    pictureBox4.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox4.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[3] == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox4.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox4.Top = 0;
                }

                if (arr[3] == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox4.Left = 0;
                    pictureBox4.Top = 150;
                }

                if (arr[3] == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox4.Left = 150;
                    pictureBox4.Top = 150;
                }
            }

            void CheckWin()
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Left==0 && pictureBox1.Top == 0 &&
                    pictureBox2.Left == 0 && pictureBox2.Top == 0 &&
                    pictureBox3.Left == 0 && pictureBox3.Top == 0 &&
                    pictureBox4.Left == 0 && pictureBox4.Top == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have won!");
                }
            }

            private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBoxKöztes.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
                pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
                pictureBox2.Image = pictureBoxKöztes.Image;
                CheckWin();

            }

            private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBoxKöztes.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
                pictureBox2.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
                pictureBox1.Image = pictureBoxKöztes.Image;
                CheckWin();
            }

            private void pictureBox3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBoxKöztes.Image = pictureBox3.Image;
                pictureBox3.Image = pictureBox4.Image;
                pictureBox4.Image = pictureBoxKöztes.Image;
                CheckWin();
            }

            private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBoxKöztes.Image = pictureBox4.Image;
                pictureBox4.Image = pictureBox3.Image;
                pictureBox3.Image = pictureBoxKöztes.Image;
                CheckWin();
            }

            private void buttonFirstCol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBoxKöztes.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
                pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox3.Image;
                pictureBox3.Image = pictureBoxKöztes.Image;
                CheckWin();
            }

            private void buttonSecondCol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBoxKöztes.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
                pictureBox2.Image = pictureBox4.Image;
                pictureBox4.Image = pictureBoxKöztes.Image;
                CheckWin();
            }

        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9dMy.png
```

Comment: How about you tell us what's wrong instead of forcing us to guess. Also recommended is using your debugger first to figure out why it's not doing what you want it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CheckWin() method is the problem.
All you are doing is checking that the left and top of the picture boxes == 0.
But there's no code moving them around, so it can't ever equal true.